# Is it possible to broadcast with WCF?

Tags: wcf

As titled, is it possible?

My concept is using WCF with duplex channel, each client application will `Login()` into the WCF and the WCF will stores the call back channel reference in the list (from `GetCallbackChannel`).

Then when broadcasting it simply iterates through the callback channel list.

But... is it possible to stores a call back channel reference and shares in different service context then broadcast it?

I know it can be done with socket (I have no idea how lol), but I just really want know if is possible to do with WCF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You can basically set up a publish/subscribe situation if you wanted to using the Callbacks you obtained with OperationContext.Current.GetChannelCallbacks().  As for your InstanceContext=PerSessions concerns, you need to realize that you will have a different service instance for each session so your callback list has to exist outside the instance.  You could make it static or singleton.  Also you have thread safety issues to consider.

This is a good article that covers publish-subscribe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx#S6

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to implement broadcasting by iterating through a list of callback channels. I am not sure what you mean by *"stores a call back channel reference and shares in different service context then broadcast it"*.

Comment: When client make call to WCF, the WCF can get the channel to callback to the client from Operation Context (I am thinking that like a location where the message to send back).  So I thought I stores that reference somewhere, then use it to call back in other thread.

Comment: Woops sorry, missed couples of words lol If I set InstanctContext=PerSession, then each client calls to WCF will have their own InstantContext, so what I mean is if that list will able to shares with all clients?